# Matrix representation in angular momentum basis

Tags: angular-momentum, scattering, representation-theory, spherical-harmonics

I'm trying to find a way to verify that the following expansion is valid for any potential, including noncentral ones,

$$
\langle \textbf{k}' |V|\textbf{k}\rangle = \frac2\pi\sum_{lm} V_l (k', k) Y_{lm}^*(\hat{\textbf{k}}')Y_{lm}(\hat{\textbf{k}})),
$$

and seeking the expression for $V_l (k', k)$.

My attempt is to insert the completeness relation
$$
\frac2\pi\sum_{lm} \int_0 k^2 dk |klm\rangle\langle klm| 
$$

to get 
$$
\langle \textbf{k}' |V|\textbf{k}\rangle = \frac 4 {\pi^2} \sum_{l'm'lm}\int_0 p'^2p^2dp'dp \langle \textbf{k}'|p'l'm'\rangle\langle p'l'm'|V|plm\rangle \langle plm|\textbf{k}\rangle \\
=\frac 2\pi \sum_{l'm'lm} \langle k'l'm'|V|klm\rangle  Y_{l'm'}(\hat{\textbf{k}'})Y_{lm}^*(\hat{\textbf{k}})
$$

and I seem to be stuck here.

Comment: What happened to the p integrals?

Comment: The overlap of momentum state and angular momentum state has a Dirac delta: < **k** |plm>=sqrt(pi/2) (1/k^2) delta(p-k) Ylm(**k**)

Comment: Should the $p$'s in your last formula (in the $\langle p' | V | p \rangle$ part) be $k$'s then?

Comment: yes, thanks for pointing out

Comment: Well now the only thing you can use is that $\langle l' m' | V (k',k) |lm \rangle = V_l (k',k) \delta_{ll'} \delta_{mm'}$, which means your potential is indeed central. The fact that you potential as no $m$ index and one total angular momentum index feels like it has to be central. I don't think such expression works for noncentral potentials?

Comment: gingras.ol I start to suspect that this works only for central forces too. I saw this on a scattering theory text stating that this is valid for all potentials while another legendre polynomial expansion is only for central ones. Looks like reducing the LS equation T=V+VGT into partial wave equations can only be done when V is central then?